# Solving $ty' + (t+1)y = 4te^{-t}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the following differential equation:
$$
ty' + (t+1)y = 4te^{-t}
$$
I first multiplied the entire equation with $\mu(t)$ and divided by $t$ to get
$$
\mu(t)y + \mu(t)(1 + \frac{1}{t})y = \mu(t)4e^{-t}
$$
Using the integrating factor $\mu(t) = e^tt$ I can write this as
$$
\dfrac{d}{dt}\big(e^tty\big) = 4te^{-t}e^t = 4t
$$
Integrating and then dividing both sides by $e^tt$ gives me
$$
y = 2te^{-t} + \dfrac{c}{e^tt}
$$
However, when the answer according to my text book looks like this:
$$
y = 2te^{-t} + (ea - 2)e^{-t}/t
$$
which means that if my answer is correct as well I should somehow be able to rewrite $\dfrac{c}{e^tt}$ to $(ea - 2)e^{-t}/t$ which is (I think) not possible.

**Question:** What am I doing wrong? How did the textbook get to this answer?

Comment: You did nothing wrong, this is just another constant $c=ea-2$. Can you check if an initial condition $y(1)=a$ is supplied?

Comment: @LutzL There isn't any but that's probably it yeah!

Comment: Also (another thing you did not do wrong) $e^{-t} = 1/e^t$.